# Cascading DropDown bindings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Here is one:

Is there anyway to see if a DropDownList control in my page is bound to an Ajax CascadingDropDown on run-time(Code)?

thanx

Answer (score 0):

You would have to iterate through all controls on your page and check if:

```
ctrl is AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDown
```

Then see if `ctrl.TargetControlID` matches the DropDownList's ID